# How do I create a Pivot Table chart Slicer that drills down from 'Cohort' to 'Class 1' and 'Class 2'?

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

Basically, I want a single slicer that when selected, will show student data based on the selection.

Individually selected, either - Cohort, Class 1 or Class 2: Single line line chart with the assessment grade.

Multi selection - Class 1 + Class 2, Cohort + Class 1, Cohort + Class 2, Cohort + Class 1 + Class 2: Double/triple line line chart with the assessment grade for a visual comparison.

[Pic of sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGacu.png)

Sample data:

| Student ID | Class | Assessment 1 | Assessment 2 | Assessment 3 | Assessment 4 | Cohort |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Class 1 | 60 | 70 | 80 | 40 | Cohort |
| 1001 | Class 1 | 65 | 75 | 64 | 45 | Cohort |
| 1002 | Class 1 | 67 | 56 | 86 | 86 | Cohort |
| 1003 | Class 1 | 48 | 58 | 84 | 48 | Cohort |
| 1004 | Class 1 | 56 | 85 | 68 | 84 | Cohort |
| 1005 | Class 1 | 67 | 86 | 48 | 48 | Cohort |
| 1006 | Class 1 | 84 | 86 | 68 | 84 | Cohort |
| 1007 | Class 1 | 67 | 56 | 48 | 48 | Cohort |
| 1008 | Class 1 | 48 | 58 | 68 | 98 | Cohort |
| 1009 | Class 1 | 56 | 85 | 70 | 80 | Cohort |
| 1010 | Class 2 | 67 | 86 | 75 | 64 | Cohort |
| 1011 | Class 2 | 85 | 68 | 56 | 86 | Cohort |
| 1012 | Class 2 | 70 | 80 | 70 | 80 | Cohort |
| 1013 | Class 2 | 75 | 64 | 75 | 64 | Cohort |
| 1014 | Class 2 | 56 | 86 | 56 | 86 | Cohort |
| 1015 | Class 2 | 58 | 84 | 58 | 84 | Cohort |
| 1016 | Class 2 | 85 | 68 | 85 | 68 | Cohort |
| 1017 | Class 2 | 86 | 68 | 84 | 63 | Cohort |
| 1018 | Class 2 | 56 | 48 | 48 | 74 | Cohort |
| 1019 | Class 2 | 58 | 68 | 98 | 65 | Cohort |

Thank you

I think the answer may lie in power pivot, but I'm still relatively new and unsure of what to do.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.